# How to perform asynchronous operation inside onProgressUpdate in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm uploading a file using retrofit2, so am trying to update my database from onProgressUpdate method while uploading a file to server, my problem is whenever i call a method that contains ExecutorService inside onProgressUpdate my main thread is blocked until that upload is completed.

```
public class MainHelpers implements ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks {

    String chatId = "ldsjkshksdmssjdsodsidjsk";

    ModelPage modalPage = null;



   public MainHelpers (ModelPage page) {
        this.modalPage = page;
    }


   
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percentage) {
       //This method call for room database update
        updateFileProgressState(percentage);

    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        //System.out.println("Progressing ERROR => ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //System.out.println("Progressing FINISHED ");
    }


    public void updateFileProgressState(int progress) {
       modalPage.updateFileProgressState(progress, chatId);
    }


}
```

This is my database method being called

```
 public void updateFileProgressState(int newProgress,String chatId) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gsLinkupDao.updateFileProgressState(newProgress, chatId);
            }
        });

    }
```

According to my findings i realized that even if i call an empty method with just ExecutorService within onProgressUpdate it still blocks my main thread.
Example: calling this blocks my main thread

```
@Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percentage) {
       //this still blocks my main thread without calling any database method
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              
            }
        });

    }
```